# how to put list in db with R

Tags: mysql, sql, r

I dont know if my question can represent what I need

I have this code :

```
i<-0 j<-0

for(i in 0:m){   j<- j+1   neighborhood <- fn$sqldf("SELECT object2
  FROM distance WHERE object1=('$j') AND neighbor=TRUE UNION SELECT
  object1 FROM distance WHERE object2=('$j') AND neighbor=TRUE ")

for (neighbor in neighborhood){
  fn$sqldf(" INSERT INTO neighborhoods(object,neighborhood) 
             VALUES ('$neighbor','$neighbor')")
```

The result of neighborhood is `(8,10,11)`

**I want to get result in table neighborhoods like:**

`(1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4, 5.5, 6.6, 7.7, 8.8, 8.10, 8.11, 9.9,` etc

but I always get this Error in postgresqlExecStatement(conn, statement, ...) :

> RS-DBI driver: (could not Retrieve the result : ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "c(8, 10, 11)"
>   LINE 1: ...TO neighborhoods(object,neighborhood) VALUES ('8','c(8, 10, ...
>                                                                ^
>   )

I just find out, how to get the result I want with some loop like this

> i <- 0   j <- 1   for (i in 0:m){     core <- fn$sqldf("SELECT core
>   FROM core_point WHERE gid=('$j')")    if (core = FALSE){
>                fn$sqldf("insert into neighborhoods(object, neighborhood) values ('$j', '$j'")             j<-j+1        }   if (core ==TRUE){
>               neighborhood <- fn$sqldf("SELECT object2 FROM distance WHERE object1=('$j') AND neighbor=TRUE UNION SELECT object1 FROM
>   distance WHERE object2=('$j') AND neighbor=TRUE ")
>
> ```
>  a <-fn$sqldf("select totalneighborhoods from core_point where gid='$j'")
>  a <- as.numeric(a)
>  for(k in 1:a){
>    o<- neighborhood[k,1]          
>    fn$sqldf(" INSERT INTO neighborhoods(object,neighborhood) VALUES ('$j','$o')")
>    k<- k+1
>  }
>  j<- j+1   } }
> ```

But I think it will gain the process, any idea? *sorry if my english is not good

Comment: help me please :(

I just want to know how to merge the number if i have a<- 8 and b<- 8, 9, 10
then the result became c< 8.8, 8.9, 8.10

Comment: Read this about creating a reproducible example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
a <- 8
b <- c(8,9,10)

paste(a,b,sep=".")  # If you need string output

as.numeric(paste(a,b,sep="."))   # If you need numeric output
```

Comment: thanks :D

I try with some looping before, because I need to insert it to database